# How to add JSON rules to filter Webview content

Tags: android, json, webview, android-webview

I'm loading a web page in android Webview and trying to add some local json-rules for filtering html content, block some ads. 
Is there any kind of controller like [WKUserContentController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller) in iOS?

I've already did some filtering by injecting Javascript using evaluateJavascript after page loaded. But also have json rules to be applied.

**Update:**

I haven't found such Controllers on Android.

Eventually I've come to the solution by using CSS injection with that rule selectors in page header using the same evaluateJavascript method.

Hope, this will help someone with similar problem.